# Ext.ajax timeout on Android

Tags: android, ajax, extjs, cordova

I have an app built on Sencha (1.1) + PhoneGap (2.9). It uploads images via an AJAX call using Ext.Ajax, which can sometimes take >60 seconds. On iOS this is fine, but on Android the request fails after 60 seconds, with an empty response. The call looks like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: /* snip */,
    headers: /* snip */,
    xmlData: xml,
    timeout: 180000,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function (response, opts) {
      /* snip */
    },
    failure: function (response, opts) {
      /* snip */
    }
});
```

I tried implementing this using $.ajax, with the result that both iOS & Android would timeout after 60 seconds. How can I get around this 60s timeout on Android?

Thanks, Stuart

Comment: Hello @stuart_gunn Did you solve this issue??  I am having the same problem on iOS.

Comment: As noted I didn't have this issue on iOS, so can't help you there sorry. On Android I fixed it by writing a new HTTP request plugin for PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with ajax requests timing out in certain browsers, you could try using filetransfer instead: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer